# Font outline using only CSS

Tags: html, css, text, outline

I'm working on adding a black font outline to white text using CSS. The goal is the image below. So far I've been able to come up with below. Is there any other best practice to closer match the thin outline shown in the image below? Thanks!

```css
.introText {
font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
-moz-text-fill-color: white;
-webkit-text-fill-color: white;
-moz-text-stroke-color: black;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
-moz-text-stroke-width: 2px;  
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
font-size: 50px;
margin-top: 20vh;
}
}
```

```html
<h1 class='introText text-center'>We've got your perfect spot.</h1>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean?! I don't see any outline in the white text of your image!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One way to do that is to use `text-shadow` and overlap multiple shadows:

```
.introText {
   text-shadow: 0 0 1px black, 0 0 1px black, 0 0 1px black, 0 0 1px black;
}
```

*4 times in this case.*

Example:

```css
.introText {
        font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px black, 0 0 1px black, 0 0 1px black, 0 0 1px black; 
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        margin-top: 20vh;
      }
```

```html
    <h1 class="introText text-center">We've got your perfect spot.</h1>
```

It creates a very similar effect and you can make it stronger or weaker depending on how many repetitions you use.

Answer (score -3):

**Maybe this is what your asking**

```css
.introText {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 100px white solid;
  margin-top: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='introText text-center'>We've got your perfect spot.</h1>
```